# Error accessing AngularJS factory methods/arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I'm dividing my functions/objects into `service` and `factory` methods, and injecting them into my controller `patentTab`. I had a code for a tab panel which I originally placed within the controller `patentTab` that worked.

Now I have placed this code in a factory method and for some reason the content isn't loading. Console log shows no errors, and when I click the relative tab the correct URL is loaded, but the content doesn't change. Is there an issue with my array in the factory? If not, what is the reason?

**Orginal code**

```
app.controller('patentTab', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.tabs = [{
    title: 'Patent Information',
    url: 'patent-info.htm'
}, {
    title: 'Cost Analysis',
    url: 'cost-analysis.htm'
}, {
    title: 'Renewal History',
    url: 'renewal-history.htm'
}];

$http.get('../json/patent-info.json').then(function(response){
    $scope.patentData = response.data.patentInfo;
})

$scope.currentTab = 'patent-info.htm';

$scope.onClickTab = function (tab) {
    $scope.currentTab = tab.url; //the tabs array is passed as a parameter from the view. The function returns the url property value from the array of objects.
}

$scope.isActiveTab = function(tabUrl) {
    return tabUrl == $scope.currentTab;
}
});
```

---

**New code (with issue)**

```
 app.controller('patentCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'patentTabFactory', function($scope, $http, patentTabFactory) {

$http.get('http://localhost:8080/Sprint002b/restpatent/').then(function(response) {
    $scope.patents = response.data;
});

$scope.loadPatentItem = function(url) {
    $scope.patentItem = url;
}

$scope.tabs = patentTabFactory.tabs;
$scope.currentTab = patentTabFactory.currentTab;
$scope.onClickTab = patentTabFactory.onClickTab;
$scope.isActiveTab = patentTabFactory.isActiveTab;

}]);
```

---

```
app.factory('patentTabFactory', function() {

var factory = {};

factory.tabs = [{
    title: 'Patent Information',
    url: 'patent-info.htm'
}, {
    title: 'Cost Analysis',
    url: 'cost-analysis.htm'
}, {
    title: 'Renewal History',
    url: 'renewal-history.htm'
}];

factory.currentTab = 'patent-info.htm';

factory.onClickTab = function (tab) {
    factory.currentTab = tab.url; //the tabs array is passed as a parameter from the view. The function returns the url property value from the array of objects.
    console.log(tab.url);

}

factory.isActiveTab = function(tabUrl) {
    return tabUrl == factory.currentTab; //for styling purposes
}

return factory;

});
```

Comment: All looks good to me, are you defining the factory before the patentCtrl ?

Comment: No after? The rest of the functionality works, yet the content won't display. Don't think the error is in the HTML as it was working before hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not calling `factory.onClickTab()` method from your controller.
It should be like :

```
$scope.onClickTab = function(currentTab) {
    patentTabFactory.onClickTab(currentTab);
    $scope.currentTab = patentTabFactory.currentTab;
};
```

and, for `isActiveTab`, Like :

```
$scope.isActiveTab = patentTabFactory.isActiveTab(currentTab);
```

Comment: Thank you! I have spent hours looking at not understanding. I thought that when the function was called, the factory handled the execution

Comment: Glad to help you :), infact you thought right but call was not reaching to factory to handle the execution. :)

Comment: Using your same logic I had to adjust the `isActiveTab` to `$scope.isActiveTab = function(tabUrl) {
        return tabUrl == patentTabFactory.currentTab;
    }`

Comment: yes you have to, but like the way i already mentioned in answer `$scope.isActiveTab = patentTabFactory.isActiveTab(currentTab);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plunker where I am using a factory. The only changes I have done are:
 1. Place the factory file before the app script file.
 2. Use a separate declaration for factories and then inject it in the app.

```
var factories = angular.module('plunker.factory', []);
factories.factory('patentTabFactory', function() {
// Factory bits
};
```

I have injected the factories in the app.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['plunker.factory']);
```

Here is a working plunker for that. [PlunkR](https://plnkr.co/edit/4NEomGHZx8BYCJsQh8ez?p=preview)

Comment: I could be missing something form the demo but I don't think it provides the outcome I'm looking for. Can I ask why two modules have been declared? Is this best practice?

Comment: I indeed is the best practise. Helps segregate the factories from everything else. It also helps in making tests more easy to read.